# Permission denied for Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Tags: android, google-maps

I am practicing on integrating *Google Maps API* with Android.

When I try to get permissions for

`Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`, permission is getting denied for `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`. However, permission is granted for `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`. I want to know the reason as to why  `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` gets denied. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `Permission is granted` how do you check that?

Comment: On androids 6+ [API level 23+] you have to check the permissions on run-time. You can find more information here:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Answer (score 0):

---

### Create this fun (Kotlin)

```
 fun setupPermissions(context:Context,activity: Activity,permission: String, requestCode: Int) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        // Requesting the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, arrayOf(permission), requestCode)
        return
    }
}
```

---

### Call after

```
setupPermissions(requireContext(),requireActivity(),*CAMERA*,234)
```